# How to dynamically create a dojo button using option such as iconClass

Tags: dojo

I want to dynamically create a dojo button, and I have issue to use option such as iconClass.

Here is I how I would create the button

```
<td valign="middle" align="
  <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'icon_btn_add', showLabel: false" type="button" onClick='require(["RouteView.js"], function( s ) { s.cb_click_btn_add(1); })' id="id_btn_add_0" 
</td>
```

I have tried

```
btn = new Button({
   "data-dojo-props": "iconClass:icon_btn_add, showLabel: false",
   "onClick": "require(['RouteView.js'], function( s ) {
      s.cb_click_btn_add("+(n)+
      "id": "id_btn_add_"+n,
      "disabled": "true"
   }, id_td3);
```

and this:

```
domConstruct.create("button", { 
      "data-dojo-type": "dijit/form/Button",
      "data-dojo-props": "iconClass:icon_btn_add, showLabel: false",
      "type": "button",
      "onClick": "require(['RouteView.js'], function( s ) { s.cb_click_btn_add("+(n+1)+"); })",
      "id": "xid_btn_add_"+n,
      "disabled": "true"
    }, id_td3, "last");
```

The "data-dojo-props" property is not taken in account.

How can I then create dynamically a dojo Button and use iconClass ?

Comment: Actually, I found the solution: just use "iconClass" as property.

    btn = new Button({
       "iconClass": "icon_btn_add", 
       "showLabel": false,
       "onClick": "require(['RouteView.js'], function( s ) {
          s.cb_click_btn_add("+(n)+
          "id": "id_btn_add_"+n,
          "disabled": "true"
       }, id_td3);

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're already creating Dojo widgets via the HTML delcaration method.  Therefore, declaring the button via the data-dojo-type attribute in HTML like:

```
<button id="an_id_for_your_button" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'icon_btn_add', showLabel: false"></button>
```

Dojo will create the button for you and record a reference to the fully created button widget in its registry with the same ID as the original button.  You can get a reference to it like so:

```
   require([ ..., "dijit/registry", ...], function(..., registry, ...) {
      var btn = registry.byId("id_btn_add_0");
      btn.set("onClick", function(e) {...});

      // Although once you are in JavaScript realm consider using "on" like
      btn.on("click", function(e) {...});
   });
```

Note the object returned by "registry.byId()" is a different object than the DOM Node returned by "dom.byId".  More info about buttons can be found: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/Button.html

For consideration it can be good practice to avoid declaring event handlers in the HTML tags (particularly with Dojo). HTML declared event handlers force the handlers to be in the global scope and controlling the "this" scope can be tricky.

Comment: Actually, my issue is to create **dynamically** the dojo button widget (I will have a bunch of them, maybe up to 30 or 40), using the two properties data-dojo-type and data-dojo-props. Even if I use "new Button", the property data-dojo-props is ignored (but all others are correctly used).